# Remote content Changes Bootstrap modal window Size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, href, bootstrap-modal

I have remote content loading data onto bootstrap3 modal.  I cannot figure out why when trigger the modal, the **modal is opened with full window sized rather than a usual normal size (i.e. width is less than current window)**.

Here is my modal trigger button:

```
{# ---- trigger button ---- #}
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" href="{% url "address_info" line_id %}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#icontact">{% trans "Address" %}</a>

{# ---- modal ---- #}
<div class="modal fade" id="icontact" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="icontactModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The remote html ({% url "address_info" line_id %}) is:

```
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header"> <h4 class="modal-title">Contact</h4></div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <table>
        <tr><th>Contact of&nbsp;&nbsp;</th> 
            <td> {{ line1 }}</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Email         </th> 
            <td>{{ email }} </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">{% trans "Close" %}</button>
</div>
```

Why the size of modal changes when using remote content?  Instead of forcing modal size through css or jquery...i think there must be something that I miss or is this expected behaviour? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now.  Simply add

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
```

at the beginning of the remote html.  That fixes the issue.